# COUNT DISTINCT with GROUP BY doesn`t work with >=

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have such statement:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT(p.`id`)) as players, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(IF(p.`created` >= 'startDate', p.`id`, NULL))) as newPlayers 
FROM `player` p 
WHERE p.`date` >= 'startDate' AND p.`date` < 'endDate' 
GROUP BY DAY(p.`date`);
```

Explaining:

I have some period of time ex: from 2019-11-11 to 2019-12-13.

I want to get information about number of players and number of newPlayers for this period but in days.

Players count works perfect, but newPlayers doesn`t.

It count not by day but for all period.

Example:

if I have 1 newPlayer at 2019-11-13 and 1 more new player at 2019-11-14 - then I want 1 newPlayer number for 2019-11-13 and 1 for 2019-11-14 - but I get 1 for 2019-11-13 and 2 for 2019-11-14.

How can I fix it?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p.id)) as players
       , SUM(case when  created >= startDate then 1 else 0 end) as newPlayers
FROM player p 
WHERE date_c >=  startDate
AND date_c < endDate
GROUP BY DAY(date_c);
```

Foer any more details you will need to give us some more details.
Please note here that I have changed name of column date to date_c.
Cheers!

To answer the firs comment, your query also works just fine without single quotes:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT(p.id)) as players, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(IF(created >= startDate, id, NULL))) as newPlayers 
FROM `player` p 
WHERE date_c >= startDate 
AND date_c < endDate 
GROUP BY DAY(p.date_c);
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=410d2bfc50c4f37f373176cb9675eec8). I know the data in the demo is not so great but...
Also , note that I have changed `AND date_c < endDate` to `AND date_c <= endDate` in this DEMO so it shows some data :)

It will also work with the correct back single quotes ```` and in your code, in some places, you have this '' and not this ``. There is a difference:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT(p.`id`)) as players, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(IF(p.`created` >= p.`startDate`, p.`id`, NULL))) as newPlayers 
FROM `player` p 
WHERE p.`date_c` >= p.`startDate` AND p.`date_c` < `endDate`
GROUP BY DAY(p.`date_c`);
```

Comment: can you explain what's the problem with `IF` and `COUNT` ??

Answer (score 0):

This statement will give you quantity of new players per day in the requested period:

```
SELECT
DAY(p.`created`),
COUNT(DISTINCT(p.id)) as newPlayers
FROM `player` p 
WHERE p.`date` >= 'startDate' AND p.`date` < 'endDate' 
GROUP BY DAY(p.`created`);
```